# How to get each element from this website (webscraping with python)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to webscrape this webpage ([www.autocar.co.uk](http://www.autocar.co.uk)). Therefore, I would like to select each Automaker in a dropdown menu. Ideally this is coded with a FOR loop to get all the entries.

As I just started coding I would higly appreciate your input!

Desired output:

```
Make
Abarth
AC Cars
AC Schnitzer
Aiways
Allard
...
Zyote
```

My code as of now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


#Inputs/URLs to scrape: 
URL = ('https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/tesla/model-3/specs')
(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
overview = soup.find()

oem_url = overview.find('select', class_='car-finder-make-chooser')

print(oem_url)
```

Output as of now:

```
<select class="car-finder-make-chooser form-select" id="edit-make" name="make"><option selected="" value="0">Make</option><option value="1286">Abarth</option><option value="2456">AC Cars</option><option value="2104">AC Schnitzer</option><option value="2112">Aiways</option><option value="1250">Allard</option><option value="90">Alfa Romeo</option><option value="91">Alpina</option><option value="1502">Alpine</option><option value="92">Ariel</option><option value="94">Ascari</option><option value="95">Aston Martin</option><option value="93">Audi</option><option value="97">BAC</option><option value="96">Bentley</option><option value="2745">Bizzarrini</option><option value="98">BMW</option><option value="1758">Borgward</option><option value="99">Bowler</option><option value="100">Bugatti</option><option value="1149">BYD</option><option value="1776">Byton</option><option value="101">Cadillac</option><option value="102">Caparo</option><option value="103">Caterham</option><option value="2805">Caton</option><option value="1719">Changan Auto</option><option value="104">Chevrolet</option><option value="105">Chrysler</option><option value="106">Citroen</option><option value="1916">Cupra</option><option value="1965">De Tomaso</option><option value="108">Dacia</option><option value="1823">Dallara</option><option value="1160">David Brown</option><option value="2800">DeLorean</option><option value="109">Dodge</option><option value="2338">Donkervoort</option><option value="1275">DS</option><option value="2042">Dyson</option><option value="1158">Eagle</option><option value="2808">Electrogenic</option><option value="1066">Elemental</option><option value="110">Eterniti</option><option value="111">Ferrari</option><option value="112">Fiat</option><option value="113">Fisker</option><option value="114">Ford</option><option value="1166">Geely</option><option value="2485">Genesis</option><option value="115">Ginetta</option><option value="2336">Gordon Murray Automotive</option><option value="116">Great Wall</option><option value="2549">GTO Engineering</option><option value="117">Gumpert</option><option value="2762">Gunther Werks</option><option value="1309">Hennessey</option><option value="1956">Hispano Suiza</option><option value="118">Honda</option><option value="1152">Hongqi</option><option value="2465">Human Horizons</option><option value="119">Hyundai</option><option value="2194">Ineos</option><option value="120">Infiniti</option><option value="1259">Isuzu</option><option value="1144">ItalDesign</option><option value="121">Jaguar</option><option value="2168">Jannarelly</option><option value="2151">JCB</option><option value="122">Jeep</option><option value="1715">JIA</option><option value="1255">Ken Okuyama</option><option value="123">Kia</option><option value="2644">Kimera</option><option value="2641">Kingsley Cars</option><option value="124">Koenigsegg</option><option value="125">KTM</option><option value="126">Lada</option><option value="127">Lamborghini</option><option value="1302">Lancia</option><option value="128">Land Rover</option><option value="129">Lexus</option><option value="2821">Lightyear</option><option value="1739">Lincoln</option><option value="130">Lotus</option><option value="2458">Lucid</option><option value="1765">Lynk &amp; Co</option><option value="1373">Mahindra</option><option value="131">Marcos</option><option value="132">Maserati</option><option value="133">Maybach</option><option value="134">Mazda</option><option value="135">McLaren</option><option value="923">Mercedes-AMG</option><option value="136">Mercedes-Benz</option><option value="1167">Mercedes-Maybach</option><option value="137">MG Motor</option><option value="139">Mini</option><option value="138">Mia</option><option value="140">Mitsubishi</option><option value="2385">MK Sportscars</option><option value="141">Morgan</option><option value="1840">MS-RT</option><option value="2505">MST</option><option value="142">Murray</option><option value="1487">NextEV</option><option value="1934">Nio</option><option value="143">Nissan</option><option value="144">Noble</option><option value="1808">Oldsmobile</option><option value="1231">Opel</option><option value="145">Pagani</option><option value="146">Perodua</option><option value="147">Peugeot</option><option value="1816">Pininfarina</option><option value="2568">Praga</option><option value="2071">Polestar</option><option value="148">Porsche</option><option value="149">Proton</option><option value="150">Qoros</option><option value="2553">Radford</option><option value="151">Radical</option><option value="1919">Ram</option><option value="152">Renault</option><option value="2499">Revology</option><option value="2787">Revolution</option><option value="2482">Rimac</option><option value="2671">Riversimple</option><option value="2761">Rivian</option><option value="2514">Rodin</option><option value="1142">Roewe</option><option value="153">Rolls-Royce</option><option value="154">Saab</option><option value="155">Seat</option><option value="1147">Senova</option><option value="1305">Shelby</option><option value="1709">Sin</option><option value="156">Skoda</option><option value="157">Smart</option><option value="2788">Smit Oletha</option><option value="158">Spyker</option><option value="159">SRT</option><option value="160">Ssangyong</option><option value="161">SSC</option><option value="162">Subaru</option><option value="163">Suzuki</option><option value="164">Tata</option><option value="165">Tesla</option><option value="1239">Tiger</option><option value="166">Toniq</option><option value="2539">Touring Superleggera</option><option value="167">Toyota</option><option value="1798">Triumph</option><option value="168">Tushek</option><option value="1110">TVR</option><option value="2754">Twisted</option><option value="169">Vauxhall</option><option value="891">Vencer</option><option value="170">Veritas</option><option value="2730">Vinfast</option><option value="171">Volkswagen</option><option value="172">Volvo</option><option value="2757">Voyah</option><option value="173">Vuhl</option><option value="2623">Wells</option><option value="2791">Wiesmann</option><option value="174">Westfield</option><option value="2142">Xpeng</option><option value="2659">Zeal Motor</option><option value="2662">Zeekr</option><option value="175">Zenos</option><option value="176">Zenvo</option><option value="1226">Zolfe</option><option value="1235">Zoyte</option></select>
[Finished in 1.8s]
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code for the current BeautifulSoup version would be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url = "http://www.autocar.co.uk/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
car_list = [x.text for x in soup.select_one('#edit-make').select('option')][1:]
print(car_list)
```

Result: `['Abarth', 'AC Cars', 'AC Schnitzer', 'Aiways', 'Allard', 'Alfa Romeo', 'Alpina', 'Alpine', 'Ariel', 'Ascari', 'Aston Martin', 'Audi', 'BAC',...]`

Also, it's `find_all` not `findAll`, if you want to use that. You can find the BeautifulSoup (bs4) documentation at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/